# Register ansible variable to different name

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a playbook where I'm running the `local_action` task (which overwrites the `ansible_host` variable with `"localhost"`) but I want to access the data that was in the `ansible_host` variable prior to the `local_action` task running, during it.

This is what I've tried so far, but I get the error `"'register' is not a valid option in debug"`

**playbook.yml**

```
- debug:
    var: ansible_host
    register: run_host

- name: Install OBS
  local_action: command ssh ansibler@{{ run_host }} "sudo /home/ansibler/obs/bin/install.sh"
  become_user: bsmith
```

The `local_action` task should ssh to localhost then run the ssh command given. The reason I'm doing it that way instead of just running the `command` task against the `ansible_host` is because I couldn't find any other workaround to make this particular script to work. It would hang indefinitely if I ran it with the `command` task.

Is there another way to achieve what I'm wanting to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reigster is not working with ansible git task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323190/reigster-is-not-working-with-ansible-git-task)

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov And correct indentation would allow OP to register the value?

Comment: @techraf yes, in Ansible you can "register" everything you would see in the output log.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov And it would be a scalar value?

Comment: @techraf stop trolling :)

Comment: Whilst @techraf has a point with it not being a scalar value, that wouldn't have mattered in this instance. Despite that, the accepted answer below is a better way than registering the string printed to the output. Thanks for the help =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the `set_fact` module is for:

```
- set_fact:
    run_host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
```