# Not able to print output

Tags: ansible, netapp

I want to print storage filer version output generated by the `na_ontap_command` module using ansible-playbooks.

I tried to register the result in a variable and print it using a debug message, but I am getting error.

```
`---
- hosts: localhost
  name: run ontap cli command
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars_files:
  - var_file.yml
  tasks:
  - name: run ontap cli command
    na_ontap_command:
      command: ['version']
      https: true
      validate_certs: false
      hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
      username: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
    register: command_result
  - debug:
      var: command_result.stdout_lines
`
```

My playbook should return the version of the storage filer `NetApp Release 9.1P8`

This is the debug I am getting:

> ```
> >TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
> ok: [localhost] => {
>     "command_result.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
> }
> ```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: `fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (na_ontap_command) module: register Supported parameters include: command, hostname, http_port, https, ontapi, password, username, validate_certs")`

Comment: Did you check this? [reigster is not working with ansible git task](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44323190/2173917)

Comment: @SouravGhosh yeah it removed my error but still I am not getting the desired output, what is changed is `ok: [localhost] => {
    "command_result.stdout_lines": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
`

Comment: Register was not well indented on the first version of your message

Comment: if you print command_result what do you have ?

Comment: @bast yes i corrected that

Comment: @bast i figured it out and posted it below.

Comment: @RavindraSinghRawat No problem, VTC as dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reigster is not working with ansible git task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323190/reigster-is-not-working-with-ansible-git-task)

Comment: `stdout_lines` is usally available in the result with `command` or `shell` module. It does not exist in your case.

Comment: @Zeitounator yeah i figured it out once i explored some of the blogs

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  name: run ontap cli command
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars_files:
  - var_file.yml
  tasks:
  - name: run ontap cli command
    na_ontap_command:
      command: ['version']
      https: true
      validate_certs: false
      hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
      username: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
    register: command_result
  - debug:
      var: command_result
```

Result after executing:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "command_result": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "<results xmlns=\"http://www.netapp.com/filer/user\" status=\"passed\"><cli-output>NetApp Release 9.1P8: Wed Aug 30 13:33:41 UTC 2017\n\n</cli-output><cli-result-value>1</cli-result-value></results>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
register: output
- name: print CLI Output
  debug: 
    msg: 
     - "output": "{{output.msg.split('\n')}}
```